# Target on click

Tags: javascript, events, target

Look this code:

```
<div>
    <a href = "#"><span>Click me MAN !</span></a>
</div>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        document.body.addEventListener ("click", function (event) {
            var target = event.target;

            alert ("Returns \"" + target.nodeName + "\". Just want \"" + target.parentNode.nodeName + "\"")
        }, false);
    }
</script>
```

You can see the element "span" inside a "link", when the "link" is clicked the current target is the same "span". How can the "event.target" return "link" instead of "span".

Thanks and no, I don't want to use "parentNode".

Comment: Why exactly are you listening for a click on the body instead of just targeting the anchor tag?

Comment: @Matt: It's a good idea to reduce event handlers to a minimum and use the fact that most events bubble up the DOM tree, a technique known as *event delegation*. This may be what the OP is doing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With your approach, you either have to manually traverse up the DOM until you hit an `<a>` element or attach the listener to the link itself and use `this`.

Minimizing the number of event listeners is generally a good idea, so here's an example of how to traverse the DOM. Note that the event listener will not work in IE, which does not support the `addEventListener()` method of DOM nodes.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/pJp4J/

```
function getAncestor(node, tagName) {
    tagName = tagName.toUpperCase();
    while (node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.nodeName == tagName) {
            return node;
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return null;
}

document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var target = getAncestor(event.target, "a");
    if (target !== null) {
        alert(target.nodeName);
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the this css tips for JavaScript. 
You will get event.target you want.

```
a > *,
button > *{
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use

```
<span><a href="#">Click me</a></span> ?
```

Comment: What is the point of the span then? It becomes completely useless.

Comment: How to you figure? The styles aplpied on it are still valid for the contents of the link...