# CSS: :focus of elements within contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus, contenteditable

If you have the following HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p>The first paragraph</p>
  <p>The second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Is there a way to style the paragraph that is being edited differently from all other paragraphs in the `div` that is `contenteditable`?

```
div > p:focus { border: 1px solid red }
```

won't be applied to the paragraph being edited.

Here's a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPNE2/)** you can play with.

How can I style the *paragraph being edited* (the `<p>`-tag) differently?

I'd prefer a CSS-only solution, but perhaps I'll have to use JavaScript.

**EDIT:**

Since we could not find a pure CSS solution (and using `:hover` is not a real solution for me) I am now looking for some lines of JavaScript that set the attribute `class="focus"` on the node that is being edited.

Comment: Please give me a hint on how I can improve my question if you downvote it.

Comment: Gah, I nearly had it working - http://jsfiddle.net/PPNE2/7/, just can't seem to remove the border when it's unselected.

Comment: @Zenith nice approach

Comment: you just need to put `contenteditable="true"` with every `p`

Comment: @optim see the answers below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I found a solution.

With the following code snippet you can get the parent element at the current caret position when the selection changes.

```
var selectedElement = null;
function setFocus(e) {
  if (selectedElement)
    selectedElement.style.outline = 'none';

  selectedElement = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
  // walk up the DOM tree until the parent node is contentEditable
  while (selectedElement.parentNode.contentEditable != 'true') {
    selectedElement = selectedElement.parentNode;
  }
  selectedElement.style.outline = '1px solid #f00';
};
document.onkeyup = setFocus;
document.onmouseup = setFocus;
```

Here I change the `outline` property manually but you could of course add a class attribute and set the style via CSS.

You still have to manually check if `selectedElement` is a child of our `<div>` with the `contenteditable` attribute. But I think you can get the basic idea.

Here's the **[updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPNE2/22/)**.

EDIT: I updated the code as well as the JSFiddle to make it work in Firefox and Internet Explorer 9+, too. Unfortunately these Browsers do not have a `onselectionchange` event handler, so I had to use `onkeyup` and `onmouseup`.

Comment: This does not work in Firefox or IE10 (probably all older IE's too).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I'll have a look on it.

Comment: +1. That's pretty much what I would have suggested. One thing is that this will fail if the user makes some text bold and then places the caret within the bold text because `window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode` will now be the bold element rather than the paragraph. I'd recommend iterating through `parentNode`s until you hit a `<p>` element instead; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4642894/96100. One other small thing: the selection can change without a key or mouse event firing (via Select All options in browser menus, for example) so you may want a polling solution as a fallback.

Comment: @TimDown Yeah that's right. It will fail if the markup within the `<div contenteditable="true">` is different. Walking up the DOM tree is something I'd expect one can figure on his/her own. A polling solution is always a bit hacky, but probably I'll have to add it for completeness. (Although I cannot think of a case where one can select a _single_ paragraph in the `<div>` without firing a mouse or a key event.)

Comment: Nice work, guys. The one change I would make is to use `outline` rather than `border`, as then the paras don't jump around as the border is added and removed.

Comment: @ralph.m I changed it. But I think this is less important for the question.

Comment: @TimDown I also added some lines that ensure the parent node is `contentEditable`.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't account for line breaks (shift+enter), rather than paragraph breaks. Here's a fiddle that can handle those line breaks http://jsfiddle.net/zcsw5731/

Comment: firefox 52 supports now [`onselectionchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onselectionchange)

Answer (score 4):

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/PPNE2/14/)

The following is imperfect in the sense that your mouse will need to be in the same area as the selected paragraph (to keep the `:hover` argument true), but as this will usually be the case anyway this should be fine - it's the best you're going to get if you want to keep your markup as it is anyway:

**CSS:**

```
div[contenteditable="true"]:focus > p:hover {
   border: 2px solid red;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div contenteditable="true">
   <p>The first paragraph</p>
   <p>The second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

---

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/PPNE2/15/)

If you're able to change the markup, you can use the following simplified selector:

**CSS:**

```
p[contenteditable="true"]:focus {
   border: 2px solid red;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
   <p contenteditable="true">The first paragraph</p>
   <p contenteditable="true">The second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm, it would be nicer not to have inline spans around a paragraph, though—at least from a validation point of view.

Comment: That second one is what I posted in my first response, but it has the issue that when you press Enter/Return, it creates a new `<div>` instead of a new `<p>`, hence my second try.

Comment: @Zenith Well, it does at least in Chrome. In Firefox it creates a `<br>` which is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. If it's viable, I'd suggest moving the contenteditable attribute to the `p`s themselves: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/FHKAC

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

div > p:focus {outline: 1px solid red; }

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div>
    <p contenteditable="true">The first paragraph</p>
    <p contenteditable="true">The second paragraph</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Here is another version, that causes para returns to generate paras instead of divs: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/dbyIa

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

div:focus {outline: none;}
div > p:focus, div > p:hover {outline: 1px solid red; }

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div contenteditable="true">
    <p contenteditable="true">The first paragraph</p>
    <p contenteditable="true">The second paragraph</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is generally what I want, but it comes with some side-effects: Say I hit return at the end of the last paragraph. In my version, a new paragraph is added. In your version it will insert a `<div>` in that `<p>`. Strange behavior... :(

Comment: Jeesh, that's odd. Well, I've added another example that seems to work. Only thing is, I had to add hover styles as well to get the focus to work on the paragraphs. Go figure.

Comment: I'm sorry, but hover state is not an option for me, since I want to indicate which paragraph you are editing even when you are not using a mouse. Maybe I'll have to work around that `<div>` insertion problem or I could find out the element around the current cursor position via JavaScript.

Comment: I updated the question, so JavaScript solutions are generally welcome.