# Using :focus with nested contenteditable elements

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I am trying to make an application to edit documents using `contenteditable`. I would like to apply a :focus state to an element, like this:

```
.focus:focus {
color: red;
}
```

However, this doesn't appear to work when the element is nested in another contenteditable element. If I have some html like this, it works:

```
<span contenteditable class="focus">content</span>
```

But if I do something like this, it doesn't work:

```
<div contenteditable>
<span contenteditable class="focus">content</span>
</div>
```

For the purposes of how I am using this, I need the outer contenteditable element. I would prefer to use css only for this. Is there a workaround for this?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tdovuyyr/)

Comment: I don't want the :focus to apply to the div, though. I want it to apply to the span with the "focus" class. Also, if I change the span in the working example to a div, it still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I added a wrapper element around the spans that cannot be contenteditable. This makes the focus work correctly.

```
<div contenteditable>
<span contenteditable="false">
<span contenteditable class="focus">content</span>
</span>
</div>
```

I don't like this solution very much, but I also don't want to add a lot of javascript to this.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/tdovuyyr/2/

```
div:focus span {
    color: white;
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: Possibly. The div contains multiple spans, and I'd prefer to only highlight the span the user is actually typing in. I guess if I don't find a better solution I'll use this.

Comment: Do you really need the contenteditable on the div in the first example?

Comment: Yes, I do, because there are other things in that div besides the span.

Comment: OK, check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832749/css-focus-of-elements-within-contenteditable