# Style inner element of contenteditable block by focus on that child element

Tags: html, css

I need to style inner `span` element which is inside of contenteditable block by focus on that inner `span`, it has to be highlighted when is focused. Is that even possible somehow?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="block" contenteditable="true" data-id="123">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <span>consectetur</span> adipisicing elit. Non facere 
            atque aspernatur, pariatur architecto inventore explicabo eligendi 
            <span>maxime</span> laudantium corrupti esse ab nostrum, 
            at quis <span>quas</span> temporibus eum? Asperiores, iste.
        </p>
    </div>
    <style>
        .block {
            outline: none;
        }
        .block span {
            background-color: antiquewhite;
        }
        .block span:focus {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please specify which inner element you have to style on the focus of `<span>`

Comment: Focus is used mainly on a input, textarea or button. Which element are you going to  focus? Maybe you need hover?

Comment: `span` is inside of contenteditable block. When the cursor is inside of that `span` - `span` has to be highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to highlight just the `span` element when you focus it try this in your stylesheet :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="block" contenteditable="true" data-id="123">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <span>consectetur</span> adipisicing elit. Non facere 
            atque aspernatur, pariatur architecto inventore explicabo eligendi 
            <span>maxime</span> laudantium corrupti esse ab nostrum, 
            at quis <span>quas</span> temporibus eum? Asperiores, iste.
        </p>
    </div>
    <style>
        .block {
            outline: none;
        }
        .block span {
            background-color: antiquewhite;
        }
     
        [contenteditable="true"] span:active {
           background-color: red;
      }
       
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

I added a simple script so the element keeps being red when the mouse leaves. Have a look :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="block" contenteditable="true" data-id="123">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <span>consectetur</span> adipisicing elit. Non facere atque aspernatur, pariatur architecto inventore explicabo eligendi
      <span>maxime</span> laudantium corrupti esse ab nostrum, at quis <span>quas</span> temporibus eum? Asperiores, iste.
    </p>
  </div>
  <style>
    .block {
      outline: none;
    }
    
    .block span {
      background-color: antiquewhite;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    let selectedElement = null;
    const setFocus = e => {
      if (selectedElement)
        selectedElement.style.backgroundColor = 'antiquewhite';

      selectedElement = window.getSelection().focusNode && window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;

      if (selectedElement && selectedElement.tagName == 'SPAN')
        selectedElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    };
    document.onkeyup = setFocus;
    document.onmouseup = setFocus;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Ok, as you requested no JavaScript and I already invested a lot of time in this question, this is my last answer. I know it is not entirely correct but it is not entirely wrong either.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="block" data-id="123">
    <p contenteditable="true">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p><span contenteditable="true">consectetur</span>
    <p contenteditable="true"> adipisicing elit. Non facere atque aspernatur, pariatur architecto inventore explicabo eligendi
    </p><span contenteditable="true">maxime</span>
    <p contenteditable="true"> laudantium corrupti esse ab nostrum, at quis </p><span contenteditable="true">quas</span>
    <p contenteditable="true"> temporibus eum? Asperiores, iste.
    </p>
  </div>
  <style>
    .block {
      outline: none;
    }
    
    .block span {
      background-color: antiquewhite;
    }
    
    .block span:focus {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    p,
    span {
      display: inline;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Similar case here:
[CSS: :focus of elements within contenteditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832749/css-focus-of-elements-within-contenteditable)

Comment: No no, I have to highlight a `span` by focus on `span`

Comment: @Nazarly I edited my answer with a proper solution for you. hope it helps :)

Comment: @Nazarly I reedited the answer, should work now. sorry for the first edit.

Comment: Works only when mouse is pressed on the `span`. Should be red when the cursor is on `span`

Comment: @Nazariy I added a simple script so the element keeps being red when the mouse leaves. Have a look :)

Comment: No JavaScript allowed

Comment: @Nazariy I added another submission. I know it is not totally right but it works as you requested no JS.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use tabindex in span tags. that will solve your problem.**

you can read more about tabindex here [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

and focus will work when you use your keyboard. in this case, use your tab to get focus in span tags.

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.block {
  outline: none;
}
.block span {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}
.block span:focus,.block span:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="block" contenteditable="true" data-id="123">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <span tabindex=0>consectetur</span> adipisicing elit.
        Non facere atque aspernatur, pariatur architecto inventore explicabo
        eligendi <span tabindex=0>maxime</span> laudantium corrupti esse ab nostrum, at
        quis <span tabindex=0>quas</span> temporibus eum? Asperiores, iste.
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Nazariy It is working fine. for focus in your span tags, use tab key.

Comment: Uhh I understand. But it’s not an option for me. Has to be by cursor.